# Issue getting the read/write split to work with PHP mysqlnd_ms

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, split, read-write

I'm trying to setup the `PHP` `mysqlnd_ms` extension and I'm having some issues. So far here is what I have done:

-[compiled PHP from source while enabling `mysqlnd`](https://sites.google.com/site/arfanahmedcheema/blog/ubuntu1204serverwithphp546andmyslqndmsqc)

-Installed `mysqlnd_ms` (If I run `pecl info mysqlnd_ms` I do get the information about the `mysqlnd_ms` plugin):

```
$ sudo pecl install mysqlnd_ms
```

-modified `PHP.ini` (and restarted it afterwards):

```
mysqlnd_ms.enable=1
mysqlnd_ms.disable_rw_split=0 ; for good measure
mysqlnd_ms.config_file=mysqlnd_ms_config.ini
```

-created `mysqlnd_ms_config.ini` with following content ([which is given as example in the official doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-ms.quickstart.configuration.php#example-1749))

```
{
    "myapp": {
        "master": {
            "master_0": {
                "host": "127.0.0.1",
                "port": "3306"
            }
        },
        "slave": {
            "slave_0": {
                "host": "localhost",
                "socket": "\/var\/run\/mysqld\/mysqld.sock"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[According to the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-ms.rwsplit.php):

> The plugin executes read-only statements on the configured MySQL
>   slaves, and all other queries on the MySQL master. Statements are
>   considered read-only if they either start with SELECT, the SQL hint
>   /*ms=slave*/, or if a slave had been chosen for running the previous
>   query and the query starts with the SQL hint /*ms=last_used*/. In all
>   other cases, the query will be sent to the MySQL replication master
>   server

So at this point I'm expecting my `SELECT` statements to be sent to the `slave` and other statements (such as `UPDATE`) to be sent to the `master`.

I wrote a little script to test the setup:

```
$socket = '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock';
$dbname = 'mysqlnsmstest';
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'root';

$mysql = new PDO("mysql:unix_socket=$socket;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);

$result = $mysql->query('SELECT * FROM mytable');
foreach($result as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}

$count = $mysql->exec("UPDATE mytable SET field='test' WHERE id=2");
echo "Nb rows affected: $count\n";
```

**The queries are properly executed *BUT* they are all sent to the `slave`** (I know this because if I sniff traffic with `$ tcpdump -ni any port 3306` I don't see anything, whereas if I make manual queries on `3306` they do show up in `tcpdump`).

Using comments such as `/*ms=slave*/` and `/*ms=master*/` makes no difference. The `general_log` does show that there isn't any other comments that could confuse `mysqlns_ms`:

```
121118 19:14:40    36 Connect   root@localhost on mysqlnsmstest
           36 Query /*ms=slave*/SELECT * FROM mytable
           36 Query /*ms=master*/UPDATE mytable SET field='test' WHERE id=2
           36 Quit
```

I tried using a non-loopback `IP` (such as my `10.0.0.56` local one) to "force" connection over the network but it makes no difference.

`$pdo->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CLIENT_VERSION)` is giving me `"mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026 - $Id: b0b3b15c693b7f6aeb3aa66b646fee339f175e39` which shows `mysqlnd` is being used.

**What am I missing in order for the read/write splitting to work (any suggestion welcome)?**

**Update:**
I found a better way than tcpdump to check whether `read/write` split is working:

```
print_r(mysqlnd_ms_get_last_used_connection($pdo));
Array
(
    [scheme] => unix:///var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    [host_info] => Localhost via UNIX socket
    [host] => 
    [port] => 3306
    [socket_or_pipe] => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    [thread_id] => 48
    [last_message] => Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
    [errno] => 0
    [error] => 
    [sqlstate] => 00000
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please, make sure to reference the PECL/mysqlnd_ms documentation section that defines the servers when trying to establish the connection. You should pass the section name - "myapp" in your example - as a host to the the connect function of the PHP MySQL API you want to use. Something like this:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=myapp;dbname=database', 'username', 'password');
```

Or, in your case something like:

```
$mysql = new PDO("mysql:host=myapp;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
```

Do not use:

```
$mysql = new PDO("mysql:unix_socket=$socket;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
```

This will connect to the very server that is listening on the socket $socket.

Comment: PDO is not happy with it as it tries to resolve `myapp` as if it were a hostname (`PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known`). `ini_get` does give me the settings I mentioned above with their correct value, including the config file which does contain the `myapp` key as shown above.

Comment: It actually works :) I had an issue with the configuration file (`Unknown: (mysqlnd_ms) Failed to open server list config file [mysqlnd_ms_config.ini] in Unknown on line 0`). Fixed in and now it's working.